# Is automatic conversion to collection types from non-collection variable a good idea?

Tags: c#, language-design

Consider

```
public void Do(string[] aBunchOfStrings) { }
```

or

```
public void Do(IReadOnlyList<string> aBunchOfStrings) { }
```

Would it be a bad idea to allow the function call

```
Do("woei");
```

resolve automatically to an internal call

```
Do(new[] { "woei" });
```

to C#?

Comment: If you might ever need to pass collections of collections, the idea will bite you.

Comment: You're trying to fix the symptom and not the problem. Just make it easier to create one-object collections.

Comment: If you need that, just add another method overload.  Is your question about c# language design, or about your particular usage?

Comment: Or, y'now, you could just write `Do(new[] { "woei" });`

Comment: It's pretty common, taking the form of `(params T[] bla)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It weakens your types, meaning the type checker will catch fewer programmer errors.  Whether you consider that a good or bad idea depends where you fall on the weakly/strongly typed spectrum.

I can think of a few situations where it might cause problems, such as if you wanted to override the function to have a separate version that just takes a bare string.  You'd have to have rules to resolve those sorts of conflicts.

Comment: Well, `Do("woei")` won't even compile without another method overload, and if you have such an overload, it's type-safe anyway.

Comment: I took the question to mean this was a proposed new language feature that didn't require explicit overloading.  If he clarifies otherwise, I will change my answer.